# Pull to Refresh expandablelistview pinch zoon in/out to increase/decrease font size

Tags: fonts, size, expandablelistview, pull-to-refresh, pinch

I have a Pull to Refresh `expandablelistview` and I need  to pinch zoom in/out to increase and decrease font size of the `textviews` inside child.

I tried several ways but when pinching, the pull to refresh view is overriding the pinch zoom.

Any Help/Ideas is much appreciated in advance.

Comment: same problem here my friend,any solutions?!